# GCP Cloud Storage: What is the difference between bucket.upload and file.save methods?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

Is there a better option for uploading a file?

In my case I need to upload a lot of small files (pdf or text) and I have to decide the best option, but anyway are there differences between these two methods?

Here two examples taken directly from the documentation

**Save method:** ([Docs](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#save-examples))

```js
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage();
const myBucket = storage.bucket('my-bucket');

const file = myBucket.file('my-file');
const contents = 'This is the contents of the file.';

file.save(contents, function(err) {
  if (!err) {
    // File written successfully.
  }
});

//-
// If the callback is omitted, we'll return a Promise.
//-
file.save(contents).then(function() {});
```

**Upload method:** ([Docs](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/Bucket.html#upload-examples))

```js
const {Storage} = require('@google-cloud/storage');
const storage = new Storage();
const bucket = storage.bucket('albums');

//-
// Upload a file from a local path.
//-
bucket.upload('/local/path/image.png', function(err, file, apiResponse) {
  // Your bucket now contains:
  // - "image.png" (with the contents of `/local/path/image.png')

  // `file` is an instance of a File object that refers to your new file.
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

At its core, both of these functions do the same thing. They upload a file to a bucket. One is just a function on `bucket` and the other a function on `file`. They both end up calling `file.createWriteStream`, so they have the same performance as well.

The functions behave differently in terms of upload type. `file.save` will default to a resumable upload unless you specify otherwise (you can set the `resumable` boolean on `SaveOptions` to false). `bucket.upload` will perform a multipart upload if the file is smaller than 5MB and a resumable upload otherwise. For `bucket.upload`, you can force a resumable or multipart upload by modifying the `resumable` boolean on `UploadOptions`.

Note that in the upcoming major version release (https://github.com/googleapis/nodejs-storage/pull/1876), this behavior will be unified. Both functions will default to a resumable upload regardless of file size. The behavior will be the same.

For small files, multipart uploads are recommended.

Comment: Thanks! Can you give me the docs for the last sentence?

Comment: We are working on better documentation for upload guidance. I will remember to post it here when it's ready. This is the documentation we currently have: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploads-downloads

The reason multipart uploads are recommended for smaller files is that it saves you a request.